# Should it be a comment or an edit to the accepted answer when it is directly opposite the original?

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits, rejection-reasons

I came upon [this](//stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/765537) in the suggested edits queue.

I am unsure if the change should be a comment as the answer is accepted (and has been for a couple of years) and it's pretty much a complete 180 for that portion of the answer.  However, it sounds like the answer is incorrect... so maybe it should be an edit to the answer.

I hit not sure/Skip, but is there another choice I should have made there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That edit, as you say, radically changes a part of the answer, and that's not generally appropriate.

A comment would have been ok, or even an independent answer *if* if had been substantial enough for that.

> However, it *sounds like* the answer is incorrect...

The edit does *look* "authoritative" with that precise reference. But do you have enough knowledge of the issue to tell whether that reference is both accurate and relevant to the question?

If not (I certainly don't), "Not Sure" is a fine course of action. It lets others deal with the suggestion, and hopefully either people with more knowledge in the topic at hand will judge based on accuracy, or the OP will have time to see the suggestion and judge for him-/herself.

Don't fear the "Not Sure" button. Whenever you're presented with a review that you're not comfortable with, letting others have a look is perfectly appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

It should be a comment. Editing should not change the meaning (except at simple typo level) or intent of a post. The edit is also referring to the naming of *variables*, whereas the original was talking about the naming of *methods*.